# Mysql Creating a Foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I need to create a foreign key for my Reviewers_POS table.
I have the Reviewers_Id as my Primary key, and i want to pass it to my id_r1 from Reviewrs_POS table..

```
    import MySQLdb as mdb
    import sys


    conexao = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'rot', 'DbOmelete')
    with conexao:  
    cur = conexao.cursor()

   cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Reviewers(Reviewers_Id int unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (Reviewers_Id),Title varchar(500), Polarity INT, Review TEXT);")
   cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Reviewers_POS(ReviewersPOS_Id int unsigned not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Review_POS TEXT,id_r1 integer,CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id_r1) REFERENCES Reviewers (Reviewers_Id));")
```

__
I'm getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "SQLTesteForeign.py", line 14, in <module>
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Reviewers_POS(ReviewersPOS_Id int unsigned not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Review_POS TEXT,id_r1 integer,CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id_r1) REFERENCES Reviewers (Reviewers_Id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'DbOmelete.Reviewers_POS' (errno: 150)")
```

Someone knows how to solve it? i'm thinking that i'am missing something.. because i really dont know "where" is the error..

Comment: Check the syntax of your second `CREATE TABLE` statement.  I do not believe your `PRIMARY KEY` clause is of correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary key is of type `int unsigned`, while your foreign key is of type `integer`, the two are not compatible. Change your foreign key to be `int unsigned` and the tables will create successfully.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86c7f/1)

Comment: but in column id_r1 i'm getting only "NULL" do you know why? i think that it supposed to be the same numbers of the id from the other table

Comment: @Marco Not unless you insert it as such... take a look [at this fiddle to see how it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4ba7/1).